# How can I run CI/CD tests for each commit/PR in parallel using github actions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, continuous-integration, github-actions

There are 180GB of samples that should be tested. Of course the testing takes a lot of time, so we want to accelerate the process. The first problem is that our CI/CD platform queues up, therefore it takes long time to complete the tests. Basically I want to store my data in the cloud, and for every commit/PR, I want to create self-hosted runner with the base image, that will test against the data in the database and will be destroyed. Basically I have those questions:

1) Do the Github action workflow run in parallel for each commit/PR?
2) How can I achieve that the base image will be created on each commit/PR and destroyed? What are the possible options? 
3) What cloud based solutions do you recommend for this purpose?

Comment: This question is too broad and part 3 is primarily opinion based. Please break down your request into individual questions and ask each one separately.